# How to write rewrite url for index.php as a request path

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite

I want to write URL rewrite for index.php as a request path and it should be redirected to the home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

This worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: This rule does more than just redirecting index.php to the homepage, it removes every `index.php` occurence  from a request and redirects to the remaining URL. But anyway if it is what you need it's good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to implement this is to use server configuration, for example if you use apache, the following rewrite command should do it (you might be able to put this also in .htaccess file)

`RewriteRule "^/index\.php$" / [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: This is for removing index.php from website URL. I have done that already. But when I insert index.php in the URL it should be redirected to the home page. For that I want to write rewrite rule, How can I do that??

Comment: My code does a redirect,  that's what `R=301` stands for: it does a redirect with HTTP Status code 301

Comment: Yes, I want to redirect. Got the answer. Thanks